# Remove a panel from woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I would like to remove panel or breadcrumbs from dashboard.storefront theme woocommerce plugin as attached in image.This can be seen under woocommerce-->order

i tried unset and css display none for class.it didn't work.

```
 .woocommerce-layout__header {
   display: none !important;
 }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j9NP.png)

Comment: Please add a screenshot so I can see where tis "panel" is located.

Comment: added screen shot

Comment: Okay, make a right click on the panel and checkout the wrapper class of the element you want to remove. Then you can replace the class used in your code snippet by the wrapper class. I think you've got the wrong class.

Comment: i checked its right...<div class="woocommerce-layout__header">

Comment: If your site is alive, please give a link, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Mr.Jo any update...coming back after long time

Comment: I can't see your code mate, sorry. So I don't know, maybe your css isn't strong enough. Try typing body  .woocommerce-layout__header ...

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
remove_action( 'in_admin_header', array( 'WC_Admin_Loader', 'embed_page_header' ) );
```